# Running a function in a jQuery implicit context

Tags: ajax, jquery-plugins, jquery

My html document looks like this:

```
<html>
 <head> .. load jquery and other stuff </head>
 <body>
   <div id="cool_container">
    <div class="cool">.. no script friendly markup ..</div>
   </div>
   <a id="cool_link">Link</a>
 <script>
    function installStuff(){
        $('.cool').coolPlugin();
        $('#cool_link').click(function(){
                $('#cool_container').load('/anothercooldiv.html');
        });
    }
    $(document).load(function(){ installStuff(); });
 </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Of course, `/anothercooldiv.html` gives another `<div class="cool"> .. etc ...</div>` fragment.

So what's the best way to turn the fresh cool div into a coolPlugin without breaking everything (and writing some nasty hacks) ?

*It'd would be great to be able to either:*

- Call installStuff with a default jQuery context '#cool_container', so I could call something like:

  `$.doThisInContext(function(){installStuff();}, $('#cool_container');`

In the `load` callback.

- Or, have an equivalent of 'live' (that would solve the problem of links if cool contains links), but on an element existence, that I could use like that in my function installStuff:

  `$('.cool').exists(function(what){ what.coolPlugin() };`

Then the `coolPlugin` would be installed on all `cool` elements now and in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest the [`.livequery()` plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery) for this still:

```
$(function() {
    $('.cool').livequery(function() {
      $(this).coolPlugin();
    });
    $('#cool_link').click(function(){
            $('#cool_container').load('/anothercooldiv.html');
    });
});
```

The important bit:

```
$('.cool').livequery(function() {
  $(this).coolPlugin();
});
```

Will run for every current and future `.cool` element as they're added, running the plugin on each.

Comment: Nice, it seems a bit old though, I wonder why the 'live' event feature has been integrated in jQuery core, and not the 'pure element match' one.

Comment: @jeje - `.live()` works in an entirely different way...it's for when events bubble up, that just doesn't happen in these cases.

Comment: This seems to check for matching nodes every 20ms.

Comment: @jeje - correct, there's no magic cross-browser event here, workarounds are all there are.

Comment: Yep, I think I'm better off changing my installStuff() to installStuff(context) where the default context is document and call that at places I like.

Answer (score 0):

Applying the plugin to the newly ajax loaded content shouldn't be too tricky:

```
$('#cool_container').load('/anothercooldiv.html', function() {
   $(this).coolPlugin();
});
```

Comment: This is what I want to avoid :)